# Launch/execute generic actions in Windows Phone, like Intents on Android

Tags: windows-phone-7

The Android framework allows for generic actions to be completed by any installed application that registers to handle the action.  You can qualify the actions with additional data, mime types, etc.

Does Windows Phone have a similar mechanism?  Is there a generic way to "launch a browser with this url", "select a file of type .xyz", "share/send this file of type .xyz", etc?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This capability does not exist to define "Intents" as it does for Android in the current v1 release of the Windows Phone SDK.

There are however a number of built in "Tasks" that behave in much the same way, including launching a Web Browser. Details here.

[How to: Use Launchers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769550%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)

[How to: Use Choosers for Windows Phone](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769543%28v=VS.92%29.aspx)